# Definindo um vetor array

Tags: delphi, pascal

Estou aprendendo Pascal e estou tendo problemas básicos de sintaxe para definir uma variável do tipo vetor.

Aqui está a declaração:

```
var
x:array[0..225] of String;
```

Gostaria de atribuir os seguintes valores e da seguinte forma:

```
x := ('X0','V1','V2','V3'),
('X1','V1','V2,'V3'),
('X2','V1','V2','V3'),
('X3','V1','V2','V3');
```

A variável `x` poderá ser acessada como `x[0,1]` sendo o mesmo que `x['X0',1]` retornando o valor `V1`, e assim sucessivamente.

Como posso aplicar isso em Pascal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Delphi/Pascal, usar Array dessa forma `x['X0',1]` não é possível. Você realmente só consegue acesso aos valores por meio do índice.

Isso para Array, criando objetos especializados é outra coisa.

O que você quer é uma matriz, que se declara com o uso de `Array` também, e se declara assim:

```pascal
var
  x: array[0..255, 0..255] of array of string;

  // ou declarando um array dinâmico, que não inicia com espaços/tamanho de uso
  // e deve ser incrementado o tamnho para uso conforme necessário
  //
  // assim:
  z: array of array of string; // claro que em qualquer uma das declaraçõeso tipo pode
                               // ser um tipo qualquer, até mesmo record´s e objetos.
```

Quanto a forma de acessar, friso que deve ser pelo índice numérico.
Exemplo:

```pascal
// leitura
value := x[254, 254];

// atribuição
x[254, 254] := value;
```

No escopo global, e somente nele, você pode fazer a atribuição direta como nesse exemplo:

```pascal
var
  matriz: array[0..1, 0..1] of integer = ((1,2),(3,4));
```

Sobre a matriz dinâmica, é importante saber ainda que a atribuição de espaços/tamanho para uso é feito com a função `SetLength`.

```pascal
// adicionar um espaço
SetLength(x, 255, 255);

// setar novos tamanhos
// 1. remover espaços
SetLength(x, 254, 254);

// 2. atribuindo mais espaços
SetLength(x, 400, 500);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Mas não há uma outra forma de atribuição? Podendo definir os 4 valores para a matriz x[0]?
Por ex: x[0]:='a','b','c','d';

Comment: Consegui aplicar no meu projeto, obrigado.